# How adding a hexadecimal value with integer work?

Tags: c, hex, literals

In the below code ,variable 'b' holds value '133' which is quite straight forward. How about variable 'a' ? Why is it '131' ?

I see the only difference is '015' instead of '15'.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a,b,c;
  a=015 + 0x71 +5;
  printf("%d\n",a);  // prints '131'
  b=15 + 0x71 +5;
  printf("%d\n",b);  // prints '133'
}
```

Can someone let me know whats going on in here ?

Comment: **hexadecimal** = base 16 = `0x{9-9A-Fa-f_]+`, every "digit" represents 4 bits, **octal** = base 8 = `0[0-7_]+`, every digit represents 3 bits. 015 is octal. Hexadecimal has won in computer history.

Answer (score 7):

Leading zeros indicate that the number is expressed in **octal**. 015 in octal is 13 in decimal notation.

> octal-literal is the digit zero (0) followed by zero or more octal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

(from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal))

Comment: Mentioning `strtol` misguided in this context. Octal integer constants have nothing to do with said standard library function.

Comment: @user694733 you're right, I adapted that.

Answer (score 3):

`015` is actually a indicator for octal number system representation, so

`015` means  `1x8^1 + 5*8^0 = 13`

So

```
  a=015 + 0x71 +5;
```

Strictly speaking means `(1*(8^1) + 5*(8^0) ) + (7*(16^1) + 1*(16^0)) + (5*(10^0)) = 133`